# Inner join in my query seems to not be recognized

Tags: sql

I have a little question about a problem with a SQL query. I've written a query to get some records and the number of occurences of those records. The problem is that I'd like to join two tables so I can get some values instead of foreign keys. This is my actual query (which I think is wrong because there is no joins in the result) :

```
SELECT date, heure_debut, heure_fin, Event_id,
       horaire_id, local_id, enseignant_id, COUNT(*) doublons 
FROM `reservations` 
INNER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`id` = `reservations`.`Event_id` 
INNER JOIN `couleurs` ON `couleurs`.`id` = `events`.`couleur_id` 
GROUP BY date,
         heure_debut,
         heure_fin,
         Event_id,
         horaire_id,
         local_id,
         enseignant_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 OR COUNT(*) = 1
```

[image: I'd like to get datas instead of foreign keys (e.g. : Event_id)]

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean "there are no joins in the result"?  I am unclear on what your question is.

Comment: There _is_ joined data leading to the result, otherwise you would not have values > 1 in the `doublons` column. You may want to add some columns from the joined tables to the group by statement, given that you want 'values' instead of FKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of a wild guess based on the OP's description of his intent.

Assuming that table `events` has a column `titre` that is an AK, the following modifications to the original query might mirror this intent. Instead of the event id it shows its name:

```
    SELECT date, heure_debut, heure_fin, `events`.titre,
           horaire_id, local_id, enseignant_id, COUNT(*) doublons 
      FROM `reservations` 
INNER JOIN `events` ON `events`.`id` = `reservations`.`Event_id` 
INNER JOIN `couleurs` ON `couleurs`.`id` = `events`.`couleur_id` 
  GROUP BY date,
           heure_debut,
           heure_fin,
           `events`.titre,
           horaire_id,
           local_id,
           enseignant_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
         ;
```